# Threading on python with time.sleep

Tags: python-3.x

I'm struggling to understand this example from a PyCon talk ([link to code example](https://pybay.com/site_media/slides/raymond2017-keynote/threading.html#fuzzing))

```
import threading, time, random

##########################################################################################
# Fuzzing is a technique for amplifying race condition errors to make them more visible

FUZZ = True

def fuzz():
    if FUZZ:
        time.sleep(random.random())

###########################################################################################

counter = 0

def worker():
    'My job is to increment the counter and print the current count'
    global counter

    fuzz()
    oldcnt = counter
    fuzz()
    counter = oldcnt + 1
    fuzz()
    print('The count is %d' % counter, end='')
    fuzz()
    print()
    fuzz()
    print('---------------', end='')
    fuzz()
    print()
    fuzz()

print('Starting up')
fuzz()
for i in range(10):
    threading.Thread(target=worker).start()
    fuzz()
print('Finishing up')
fuzz()
```

The above would print something like:

```
Starting up
The count is 1The count is 2The count is 2The count is 2


---------------The count is 3
---------------The count is 4
---------------
---------------The count is 4


The count is 5------------------------------
Finishing up


The count is 5
------------------------------



The count is 6---------------
---------------
```

What I don't understand about this is why sometimes, when a thread is put to sleep it continues from where it left off and other times it stops and starts the next iteration.

EDIT:

- I clearly missed the for loop...

Comment: _Given it's just one thread_ There are 10 threads all trying to use the same global variable.

Comment: obviously, not even sure how I skipped over that part... still though why do some threads don't resume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the threads run to completion. That's the point of the lesson. When multiple threads access the same variable simultaneously, you can get unexpected results.

I've modified the code slightly to print less distracting stuff and also a thread id. I think this should help clarify what is happening:

```
import threading, time, random

##########################################################################################
# Fuzzing is a technique for amplifying race condition errors to make them more visible

FUZZ = True

def fuzz():
    if FUZZ:
        delay = random.random()
        time.sleep(delay)
        return delay

###########################################################################################

counter = 0

def worker(id):
    'My job is to increment the counter and print the current count'
    global counter

    fuzz()
    oldcnt = counter
    delay = fuzz()
    counter = oldcnt + 1
    print('%d> After %s seconds, the count is %d -> %d' % (id, delay, oldcnt, counter))


print('Starting up')
fuzz()
for i in range(10):
    threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(i,)).start()
    fuzz()
print('Finishing up')
fuzz()
```

Example output (because of the randomness, this will change each run):

```
Starting up
0> After 0.7350378311578315 seconds, the count is 0 -> 1
2> After 0.1785671063273092 seconds, the count is 1 -> 2
1> After 0.8294767498326181 seconds, the count is 0 -> 2
3> After 0.5901283670333175 seconds, the count is 1 -> 3
4> After 0.14964432977752684 seconds, the count is 2 -> 3
7> After 0.07459495416247286 seconds, the count is 2 -> 3
5> After 0.24680028896240813 seconds, the count is 1 -> 2
8> After 0.18685884099452443 seconds, the count is 3 -> 4
Finishing up
6> After 0.8512297712462166 seconds, the count is 2 -> 4
9> After 0.5959592400151894 seconds, the count is 4 -> 5
```

Because of the random sleep times between when the variable is stored (`oldcnt = counter`) and when it is incremented (counter = oldcnt + 1) you get the data race.